# System.Windows.Forms - RemoteWebDriver -> Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, azure-devops, remotewebdriver

We have a problem with my team for several weeks.
We currently have a test in MSTest v1 and Selenium 3.11 that is dedicated to upload a photo when filling out a profile.
In local works perfectly (hehehe), but in remote (RemoteWebdriver) the server of Build & Releases (VSTS) throws an error just in the step where I interact with this window, of the Access Denied type.
It is not really Selenium who acts there, but the System.Windows.Forms library and the SendWait method of the SendKeys class that gives the error when it is launched remotely.

Screenshot of the element in question >>> [UploadFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72XRb.png)

Example code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.IO;

//...

public class EditarFotoUsuarioAdministrador
    {

    public static void Execute(IWebDriver driver, string foto)
    {

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='upload']")).Click();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        SendKeys.SendWait(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + foto);
        SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='save']")).Click();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); 


    }

}
```

As I said, this in local works perfectly, but when it runs on the remote server, the whole test goes well until it reaches the SendKeys line:

[AccessIsDenied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgnC5.png)

Hopefully someone has an answer, thank you very much !!

Comment: Why are you using Windows forms methods to interact with the application instead of using the Selenium methods?

Comment: Is the build/release agent running as interactive mode?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT exactly, and not run :(

Comment: Do you mean it is running as service mode?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT not, in a task. i test as service mode, and the result are the same

Comment: What's the result if the agent running as interactive mode?

Comment: The agent need to be running as interactive mode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#choose-interactive-or-service-mode

Answer (score 0):

The agent need to be running as interactive mode.

Comment: Edited post:
Screenshot of the element in question >>> UploadFile

Comment: @DaniCaoma not clear what's the screenshot used for, can you use FindElementById().SendKeys method?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it using **AutoIT3**.
Loading the nuget and using its methods to send the path of the file, you can perfectly interact with any pop-up browser window.
And best of all, the remote server does it too.
Thank you very much to all !

Answer (score 0):

AutoIT3 or AutoItX.Dotnet ? 
can you please send the code snippet. i used below code

```
` AutoItX.WinActivate("Open");
  AutoItX.ControlGetFocus("Open");
  AutoItX.Send(file);
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
  AutoItX.ControlClick("Open", " ", "Button1");`
```

It works fine in local but not in remote